# The ApexClass name was not found in the workspace VSCode

Tags: apex, failing-tests, vs-code

Today I started to work on apex test class file after retrieve the source from the Sandbox I realized that the name of file is wrong I deleted the file test and the -meta.xml but when I retrieve again the code from Sandbox and I try to upload I received this error:

**SourceElementDoesNotExist: The ApexClass named RestCalloutSchedulerTest was not found in the workspace.**

I don't understand which is the problem
Can anyone to help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

@Ionut Buzatu If you are creating a new meta and a class file, try saving the -meta.xml first and then try with the class. Hope it should work.